# WorkbookBeforeClose Event not firing

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Afternoon all,

This seems a simple thing but I am out of ideas. I want to prevent the save message when closing the Excel. I have had intermittent problems in the past with similar code but it still worked for the most part. However, the code below doesnt seem to fire at all.

I have read and attempted a few suggestions such as:

- Ensuring the code is in ThisWorkbook
- Ensuring EnableEvents is on
- Exit completely and reopen Excel after triggering once (intermittent fire bug)

I have tried breakpoints and debug statements to catch the WorkbookBeforeClose when it fires but it is just being ignored.

```
Private Sub WorkbookBeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Application.EnableEvents = True
Debug.Print "Closing"

'Suppress save notifications on close
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'restart on open

ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: The Event is called `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)`, not `Private Sub WorkbookBeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)`

Comment: In the VBA code editor window for ThisWorkbook select *WorkBook* from the left drop-down at the very top and then *BeforeClose* from the drop-down on the right.  You can see the correct name is `Workbook_BeforeClose`

Comment: Can't see the woods for the trees. Stars, thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the underscore...
`Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)`